# Non-Java source "on the classpath"?

Tags: java, classpath

At work our Java applications use all sorts of non-Java "source" (input) files (XML, properties files, etc.) for runtime configuration.

I've heard co-workers use verbiage like "is log4j.properties on the *classpath*?"

It's obvious that what they mean by this is: *can Java "see" the resource?* If we're talking about code running locally (inside Eclipse), then the files must be in a location where the Eclipse workbench can find them. If we're talking about automatically building a project from a CI server, then the Ant running on that server must be able to find/see those resources.

My question: **is this proper Java terminology for non-Java sources, or is this just a idiom used at my place of work?** How can something that isn't a *class* exist on the *class* path?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpath is just the collection of paths the JVM looks at when trying to resolve the a resource, whether it is a source file or not.  If you look at the [Java documentation for resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/resources/resources.html) it says

> ...locating a system resource may involve searching the entries in the CLASSPATH

So I think it is perfectly valid to say "is such-and-such resource on the CLASSPATH?"  Besides, it gets the point across and I can't think of a better way to ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

No, they really do mean (and very correctly so) the classpath, which is a collection of directories or JAR files in which the JVM searches for classes *and also for resources like image and configuration files* to be accessed via mechanisms like [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

This is actually the preferred way to deploy resources for a Java application, since it does not require the application to be configured so it can find the resources, nor does it depend on the application's "installation directory" (which is not a popular concept in the Java world, since it's kinda mushy when your application is running in an app server).